# How to make TypeScript type check object literals with dynamic keys?

Tags: typescript

I'm a bit confused on how TypeScript performs type checking when using dynamic keys in object literals. Consider the following two functions returning a copy of an object:

```
type Foo = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
};

const INIT_FOO: Foo = { a: 0, b: 0 };

function test1(k: keyof Foo) {
  const f: Foo = { ...INIT_FOO, [k]: true };
  return f
}

function test2(k: keyof Foo) {
  const f: Foo = { ...INIT_FOO };
  f[k] = true;
  return f
}
```

The TypeScript compiler will [only report errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBDAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuTKM-Y8q2gX1vQGM4CBnYKAEkAcoIAqAfRgB5afniIUqHPgAMAGnpqo7dOgBmRAp2ABLHlGAR+ARgAUAa3wOIIOPtgIAlGjrc+AvryCMhoUAB0kSLiUrKaANoOALr4wJRE0LpYlBDARJQEUProrHqGxmYWVvwATI7Oru6ecD4YWP78RcGKYZHh0ZIy0jq0WPqJSaFpGaNQOXkFRSXoQA) for function `test2`, and not function `test1`.

Why doesn't the compiler report an error for function `test1` when it is clearly incorrect?

Comment: I bet this is another situation where the answer is "It could, but it would either be too complex to code and maintain in the compiler or too costly to check at runtime" (though I don't know why that would be).

Comment: But have you done a thorough search of the [issue list](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)? It could just be a bug.

Comment: Could be related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40529

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#38663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38663).  It happens because computed properties where the key is a union of string literals (like `keyof Foo`) are widened to a `string` index signature.  It's not exactly *incorrect*, but it is not specific enough to be useful.  This behavior is either a bug, as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), or possibly a design limitation, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#21030](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030).  In any case, this is the current behavior of the language.

Once the computed property is widened to an index signature, it becomes impossible to catch the bug.  Index signatures are not considered excess properties; the type `{a: number, b: number} & {[k: string]: boolean}` (which is approximately what you get here) is assignable to `{a: number, b: number}`, so no bug is reported. But of course, in actuality, what you've done is assign a `boolean` to one of the `a` or `b` properties; it's just that the compiler can't see it because of the index signature widening.

---

Other than just making a note of this issue and being careful, the other thing you could do is manually implement a function that produces the type that "should" be generated when you have a computed property of a union of key types:

```
function computedProp<K extends PropertyKey, V>(
  key: K, val: V
): K extends any ? { [P in K]: V } : never {
  return { [key]: val } as any;
}
```

The return value is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) that produces a union of object types, like this:

```
const example = computedProp(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b", true);
// const example: { a: boolean; } | { b: boolean; }
```

The union `{a: boolean} | {b: boolean}` is a more accurate representation of the type of `{[k]: true}`.  If we use that, you get the expected error:

```
function test1(k: keyof Foo) {
  const f: Foo = { ...INIT_FOO, ...computedProp(k, true) }; // error!
  //    ~
  // '{ a: boolean; b: number; } | { b: boolean; a: number; }' is not assignable to 'Foo'.
  return f
}
```

Obviously using a function instead of a direct computed property is not really desirable, but at least you could sort of maintain type safety if it's important to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBDAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuTKM-Y8q2gX1vQGM4CBnYKAEkAcoIAqAfRgB5afniIUqHPgAMAGnpqo7TOgBmRAp2ABLHlG4kwRYBAAmABUpwwAHgDSUCAA87Be14oZ1cqUA8IEE0ANQA+AAo6AGtI-A9NADdsABt8aPQASjTvPwgAoOwCECgAfjQoAG1HKFMCKA8AXTydKEYIDKo0OkoIYCJKNuUGlJAuqCzsnuwKqrZ0Lh5+EuxrbOgUKxs7JxcweIBZbGAACwA6Skr7OBJ4gqg3KFVbgFZaqAAibD-XoAsj-TTAShECAFWgAejhlk2Al8OzAe3wyjw9AQe0q1B6AB96gwcXA8QQCax1oZjGYLHZ+ABGeJJfAzOD6WAIN4YLDcPgCfTyBDIeq3CUicRSWSaCW3Q62BwhM5JCFQmE6AkI7yUFyUACEdB1WCgAD9jYixOBoAByLH4Mi4iD4rSEUgUGhEkmO52u7FMT1U20tIIEOACZa8UwAcwI2DIeygwEQoEgUFtCltt2Go3GbX06Gp6CAA)